# Change boolean value when conditional rendering in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

How can I go about changing a boolean value after conditionally rendering something in react?

I want to make a conditional render in React and afterwards change the value of a boolean used in the condition, but have no idea on how you do it. It's something simple that is useful so i suspect it is possible somehow, but have no idea about the correct syntax/method and my google search results are filled with irrelevant stuff.

```
let hasBeenPrinted = false
return(
 {deals.map((deal) => (
   deal.value>10000 && !hasBeenPrinted && <h4>Congratulations on your first big deal</h4>
   <Deal deal={deal} />
)
)
```

So what I want to do here is to change the value of hasBeenPrinted to true so that the congratulations text will only be printed once.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ***deals.map((deal, index)=>{ ... })*** and check if the index is 0 to print congratulations only the first time. Changes reflected in your code would be as such.

```
return(
 {deals.map((deal,index) => (
   deal.value>10000 && index == 0 && <h4>Congratulations on your first big deal</h4>
   <Deal deal={deal} />
)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, `deals` is an array that can have multiple "big deals" (`deal.value > 10000`). However, you want to make sure that "congratulations..." is printed at most 1 time even if there are, say, 7 big deals in `deals`?

If that's correct, it sounds you would be better off filtering `deals` like so

```
const hasBigDeal = deals.some( deal => deal.value > 1e4)
```

and then conditionally rendering the `<h4 />` based on `hasBigDeal`. I don't believe updating react state or a local variable such as `hasBeenPrinted` is appropriate here as the information you care about already exists before the render (`return`) statement.

Your final code would look like this:

```
const hasBigDeal = deals.some(deal => deal.value > 1e4);

return(
  <>
   {hasBigDeal && <h4>Congratulations on your first big deal</h4>}
   {deals.map((deal) => <Deal deal={deal} />)}
  </>
```

And in case you are not already aware, there are tons of super helpful methods exposed on the Array object in javascript that can make your life a ton easier. In my example above, I used `Array.some` (link to MDN docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some))

Also, the `<>...</>` is called a React Fragment which is also very useful if you haven't heard of them either (link to [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax))